# Angular 2 (tour of heroes) tutorial: ERROR in src/app/mock-heroes.ts(1,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './hero'

Tags: angular

I am going through the tutorial and doing everything as it says until I get to this section of the tutorial where it throws me this error. I have the hero class defined so I am confused as to why it is throwing me this error. I have restarted the program all together and even re-created the mock-heroes type script. I am using Visual studio code so here is my code for the two files:

Hero class defined in hero.ts:

```
export class Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

mock-heroes.ts:

```
import { Hero } from './hero'; <----- Error is coming from here 

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Deku' },
    { id: 12, name: 'All Might' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Todoroki' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Naruto' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Ichigo' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Goku' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Vegeta' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Natsu' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Megaman' },
    { id: 20, name: 'One Punch Man' }
  ];
```

Folder structure on laptop:

```
angular-tour-of-heroes/src/
    app/
        mock-heroes.ts
        heroes/
            hero.ts
```

Comment: Please post folder structure also

Comment: Specifically: is `hero.ts` in the same directory as `mock-heroes.ts`? If not, the path is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is to change path to:

```
import { Hero } from './heroes/hero';
```

Comment: Thank you so  much so I was misleading it to think it was one folder when it was in the other

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's because of folder structure do change the import as below

```
import { Hero } from './heroes/hero';
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Angular Tutorial: create a hero interface](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#create-a-hero-interface) instructions, the location of hero.ts should be in the `app` folder ( here: `src/app/hero.ts` ) and **not** `src/app/heroes/hero.ts`

With that file structure, the path in `heroes.component.ts` should be:

`import { Hero } from '../hero';`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `hero.ts` to the folder `src/app/hero.ts` instead of `src/app/hero/hero.ts`.

I know Angular indicates creating this `hero` folder. Just dismiss it.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a similar error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../mock-heroes' in 'E:\Angular\project1\src\app'

ERROR in src/app/hero.service.ts:2:22 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../hero1' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Folder structure:

```
project1/src/
          app/
          hero1.ts
```

and I spent some time to short out this error, Finally the problem is that I have imported the file which is in the different folder

> import { Hero } from '../hero1.ts';

If you notice **'../hero1'** there is no such path in my folder structure
just by removing a dot **'./hero1'** the code compilers properly.

After removing a dot

> import { Hero } from './hero1';